# Peer authentication failed for user with all privileges in Postgres 9.5

Tags: postgresql, privileges

I want to create a user who only has access to a specified database. However, it should have all permission. I use Postgresql 9.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. So first of all, I create a new user:

```
$createuser --interactive joe
  Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n
  Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) n
  Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) n
```

Next I create a new database with owner joe:

```
 $sudo -u postgres psql 
 $CREATE DATABASE myDB OWNER joe;
 $GRANT ALL ON DATABASE myDB TO joe;
```

After that, I try to connect with user joe to connect on my database myDB:

```
$psql myDB -U joe
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "joe"
```

What i have to do next?

Comment: This is not Off-topic. because setting up software in Ubuntu is on-topic

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Open `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` with root access

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
   ```
2. Change `peer` to `md5` in these lines.

   Before changing

   ```
   # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
   local   all             all                                     peer
   # IPv4 local connections:
   host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            peer
   # IPv6 local connections:
   host    all             all             ::1/128                 peer
   ```

   After your change

   ```
   # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
   local   all             all                                     md5
   # IPv4 local connections:
   host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
   # IPv6 local connections:
   host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
   ```
3. Save the file with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>. Exit nano with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>
4. Restart postgresql using

   ```
   sudo service postgresql restart
   ```

Comment: thank you, i had to change the line local peer to md5, after that i could login successfully.

Comment: Updating for any version:, to check the conf file: `sudo -u postgres psql -c "SHOW config_file"`

Comment: Mine were showing ident instead of peer, `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 ident`, `host all all ::1/128 ident`